# How to understand this recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

> Find the number of ways that a given integer x can be expressed as the sum of the nth power of unique, natural numbers.
>
> ex: If x=10, n=2. The only possible case is : 3^2 +1^2

Here is the solution I read some somewhere:

```
int solve(int x, const vector<int> &powers, int index) {
    if(index == 0) {
        return (x == 1) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    // else
    if(x == powers[index])
        return 1 + solve(x, powers, index - 1);
    // else
    int res = 0;
    res += solve(x - powers[index], powers, index - 1);
    res += solve(x, powers, index - 1);
    return res;
}


int main() {
    int x, n;
    cin >> x >> n;
    
    int pow = 1;
    vector<int> powers;
    for(int a = 2; pow <= x; a++) {
        powers.push_back(pow);
        pow = power(a, n);
    }
    
    cout << solve(x, powers, powers.size() - 1) << endl;        
    return 0;
}
```

Here I'm not able to actually visualise it. How to think recursively? Please explain the solve function ?

Comment: Either draw it out on paper, each recursive call indented or like a tree. Or use a debugger to step through the code, stepping into the recursive calls (and *still* draw the calls out on paper)

Comment: *How to think recursively?* You need to understand recursion first.

Answer (score 4):

For better understanding the recursion I propose you to run the following code, that provides visualization for function call (entrance) and return:

```cpp
#define TRACKING

#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef TRACKING
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
const unsigned int maxOutOffset = 60U;
#endif

using namespace std;


int solve(int x, const vector<int> &powers, int index)
{
#ifdef TRACKING
    int outputOffset = min(powers.size() - index, maxOutOffset);
    cout << setw(outputOffset) << ">" << " entrance with index = " << index << " and x = " << x << endl;
#endif
    int res = 0;
    if (index == 0) {
        res = (x == 1) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else if (x == powers[index])
    {
        res = 1 + solve(x, powers, index - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        res += solve(x - powers[index], powers, index - 1);
        res += solve(x, powers, index - 1);
    }
#ifdef TRACKING
    cout << setw(outputOffset) << "<" << " return with index = " << index << " and res = " << res << endl;
#endif
    return res;
}


int main() {
    int x, n;
    cout << "x ? : ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "n ? : ";
    cin >> n;

    int power = 1;
    vector<int> powers;
#ifdef TRACKING
    cout << "Powers privied to solve method:" << endl;
#endif
    for (int a = 2; power <= x; a++) {
#ifdef TRACKING
        cout << power << ", ";
#endif
        powers.push_back(power);
        power = pow(a, n);
    }
#ifdef TRACKING
    cout << endl << "Tracking the recursive solution:" << endl;
#endif
    cout << "Results is "<< solve(x, powers, powers.size() - 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result of running with `x = 10` and `n = 2` is as follows:

[image]

I really hope, that proposed tracking will help you to understand the recursion and to make your solution better (corresponding to the task).

**UPDATE:**

If you delete the first line (`#define TRACKING`) output will be the following:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Recursion is a form of expession some function with help of the same function. E.g.: `n! = n*(n-1)!`

If we think about your particular case (task of finding/counting `n` numbers in array of powers that make `x` with summation)
task can be expressed as:

> starting from the biggest number in the array try to make summ of n items that makes x,
>
> where adding next number expressed like
> number_count_i(x) = 1 + number_count_i-1(x-item[i])
>
> and we should stop when x is equal to item[i]

Perhaps, I am not really strict, so try to think in such way and draw picture at paper (that really helps).

Comment: Thank you. I know how to debug, can you please tell me how to solve a problem on recursion. I mean we have to assume we have an answer to some part of the problem and then we build upon that, taking care of the base case

Answer (score 0):

> How to think recursively?

In a crude pantomime of creating a MCVE, let me first 'minimize' the function by 'hiding' most of the non-recursion issues:

```
int solve(... int index) 
{
    if(index == 0)   // termination clause
        return (x == 1) ? 1 : 0; // result

    // else
    if(x == powers[index])
        return 1 + solve(... index - 1);  // recurse

    // else
    {
      int res = 0;
      res += solve(... index - 1);  // recurse
      res += solve(... index - 1);  // recurse
      return res;
    }
}
```

Notice how the parameter (index, in this case) is decremented at each of 3 invocations of solve().  This action ultimately leads to the termination case.

Remembering how this effort gets to the termination clause, now imagine, as part of this thought experiment, that each invocation of "solve(index)" is transformed into a uniquely named function:

```
solveN(), ... solve3(), solve2(), solve1(), solve0(),
```

where solveK() maps to solve(K).  This form, a 'normal' function call, should be recognizable, and is merely a 'disguise' for the original recursion form.

(do we need to know how many calls?  this is a thought experiment, so, no.)

Now, let us inspect the much simplified function call stack for index 3 down to 0. The essentials are

```
solve3(...) { return (solve2(...)); }

   solve2(...) { return (solve1(...)); }

      solve1(...) { return (solve0(...)); }

         solve0(...) { returns 0 or 1 }
```

That foo() might call bar() might call bric()  call brac(), is probably normal and recognizable by you.  Each function does some part of the overall effort, and each returns, shall we call it, an 'internal' result, which is (possibly) refined as each function returns to it's caller.

The indentation in the call stack is suggestive of automatic variable space use (which is called stack on most hw architectures) ...

Summary - a recursive call is *completely* like any function call. A N deep recursion must return N times, and where each returns to is exactly like any normal function return location, i.e. just after the invocation.

Every recursion needs at least one termination clause.  And it is an error to have code that does not terminate (even though it has a termination clause).

Hope this helps.